# How do I tell an if statement to do something if it's one greater or less than a random other number?

Tags: java

not the exact program but essentially if I have something like

```
public class WereWolfenstein2D {
public static void main(String[] args){
 {Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 Random number = new Random();   
 int office;
 int hitmenlocation;

    office = 1+number.nextInt(16);
    hitmenlocation = 1+number.nextInt(16);
```

and then I want to do an if statement saying that if office is one greater or one smaller than hitmenlocation then something should happen, like print a message. How do I type that sort of a comparison statement out?

Comment: Is that really JavaScript?

Comment: This looks more like C# or Java than Javascript.

Comment: oh damn sorry i used the wrong tag!  it is java

Comment: `if ( Math.abs(office-hitmelocation) == 1 )`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if statement saying that if office is one greater or one smaller than hitmenlocation

Directly translated to...

```
if( (office - hitmenlocation) == 1 || (office - hitmenlocation) == -1) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

A cleaner way of doing this is...

```
if(Math.abs(office - hitmenlocation) == 1) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't  used Math.abs before, this is exactly what I needed